# Execute gunicron as non-root user, but python says it's root

Tags: django, root, gunicorn, supervisord

So in the `top`

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND    
11329 gunicor+  20   0  177236  51472   7888 S  0.0  8.5   0:00.49 gunicorn                                                    
11326 gunicor+  20   0  164408  44456   7392 S  0.0  7.4   0:00.40 gunicorn                                                    
11318 gunicor+  20   0   56428  16960   6368 S  0.0  2.8   0:00.14 gunicorn                                                    
16735 root      20   0   60952   9044   3972 S  0.0  1.5   7:27.77 supervisord
```

We can see `gunicorn` was run by user `gunicorn_user`.

But in python code

```
# Below prints gunicorn_user
import commands
commands.getoutput("echo $(whoami)") 
>>> gunicorn_user

# This reports root
import getpass
getpass.getuser()
>>> root
```

When I refer to ~/.file, this file will go to `root`, but I need `gunicorn_user` instead.

Why is there an inconsistency?  How can I fix it so `~/` will refer to `/home/gunicorn_user/`

**Append my supervisor config**

`[program:app]
command=/webapp/bin/gunicorn_start
user=gunicorn_user
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true`

And my `gunicorn_start` file

`exec gunicorn \
    --name $NAME \
    --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
    --max-requests $MAX_REQUESTS \
    --timeout 30 \
    --user gunicorn_user --group webapp \
    --log-level debug \
    --bind unix:$SOCKFILE \
    app.wsgi`

Comment: This show root is running superviser not gunicorn. As to the getpass.getuser() are you doing that from the python console?

Comment: @e4c5 No, not from console, part of other pieces of code.